# Using the CONVERT() in WHERE Clause to convert varchar to date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to know how to achieve the following: I want to convert a `varchar` to a `date` format but so far I'm not very successful...

My date (`varchar`) looks something like this: `02-02-2012 11:48 AM`

And I want to convert it to the following this: `dd-mm-yyyy` to be able to use the `BETWEEN` clause in the end.

I have the following script but it is not executing the way I want it to. What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to work? Any help will be much appreciated!

```
SELECT 
    Con_Consult_Date
FROM 
    Consultation
WHERE 
    CONVERT(varchar(30), Con_Consult_Date, 105) BETWEEN '01-01-2013' AND '31-12-2013'
GO
```

Comment: You need to convert your `varchar` to a `datetime` (or better: `datetime2(3)` - so you need to use `CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), ...)`. You're currently converting **to a `varchar(30)`** and that's not helpful....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `convert` and `Cast` the `Date` and then use it in the `BETWEEN` clause. Try this.

```
SELECT Con_Consult_Date
FROM Consultation
WHEREE CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, Con_Consult_Date, 105), 101) AS DATE) 
BETWEEN CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-01-2013', 105), 101) AS DATE) 
AND CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, '31-12-2013', 105), 101) AS DATE)
GO
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks a lot! I'm not very used to work with CAST as I am sort of new to sql... So I'll study that piece of code for future reference.

Comment: @MFJones: I'm glad this worked for you but please note that there's absolutely no need for so many conversions. This would work just fine: `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Con_Consult_Date, 105) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '01-01-2013', 105) AND CONVERT(DATE, '31-12-2013', 105)`. And if you can afford using a different format for the arguments, you can simplify that even further: `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, Con_Consult_Date, 105) BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'`. Also, consider [using open-ended ranges](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).