# SQL where clause with one parameter to check either int or string field

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getClassInfo](@ClassId int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [usergroupId]
      ,[gName]
        ,[accessCode]
  FROM [dbo].[usergroup]
  where usergroupid = @ClassId OR accessCode = @ClassId
END
```

Now, I want the parameter I'm sending to check either `usergroupId` which is a number or `accessCode` which is a string.

Which solution is painless to check for both cases using one parameter?

Comment: Take a look to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28893836/using-the-convert-in-where-clause-to-convert-varchar-to-date  but in your case convert to varchar()

Comment: Change `accessCode` to a number in your table.

Comment: @ClassId as an int will never possibly be able to hold all of the values that accessCode ***could*** be, you should probably work with a string as the parameter, and maybe tryparse it to an int... but this seems like you should just use two parameters.

Comment: you can do like this `OR accessCode = CAST (@ClassId AS VARCHAR(30))`

Comment: @juergend I can't change to a number since that's a string, it includes text

Comment: Are you on a weird SKU of SQL Server where you have to pay for each parameter you use? If not, I'd suggest using separate, named, parameters for each potential match rather than trying to create a swiss-army-knife parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have none integer values in your parameter so have changed to varchar.

```
Alter Procedure [dbo].[getClassInfo] ( @ClassId Varchar(50) )
As
    Begin
        If IsNumeric(@ClassId + '.0e0') = 1
            Begin
                Declare @ClassIdInt Int = Convert(Int , @ClassId);

                Select  [usergroupId]
                      , [gName]
                      , [accessCode]
                From    [dbo].[usergroup]
                Where   @ClassIdInt = [usergroupid];
            End; 
        If IsNumeric(@ClassId + '.0e0') = 0
            Begin
                Select  [usergroupId]
                      , [gName]
                      , [accessCode]
                From    [dbo].[usergroup]
                Where   [accessCode] = @ClassId;
            End;
    End;
```

The if statement determines if the value passed is an integer and then runs the appropriate query

Comment: An `ISNUMERIC` check doesn't guarantee that the value can be converted to an `int`. It answers the question nobody ever wanted to ask "can this string be converted to any of the numeric types?".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the spot, updated the code to test specifically for integers as per this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358147/best-equivalent-for-isinteger-in-sql-server

Comment: I'd declare a variable above the `Select` statement and put that `Case` statement up there. No sense evaluating it for each record if you don't have to.